# Apache Kafka using both log compaction policy or how clean old compacted log

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I`m new in kafka and have some qustions.
If I understand correctly, before 0.8 kafka version we had only one way to retention log: delete old logs part and set this time with parameter **log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms**.
Now we can choose **compact** setting in parameter **log.cleanup.policy** which will delete duplicates for same keys in logs tail. 
But is there any way to implement this scenario: compact recent messages and delete too old parts of this log?
Sorry for my bad English, but I really want understand kafka.

Answer (score 0):

Well,it depends on what you mean by "old records".As far as i know you cannot mix "compaction" with deletion in terms of time/size.But with compaction you can delete records(NOT just duplicates) by sending a key with a null value.But you would have to decide manually which "keys" u say are old and then send those keys will nulls as values.

So to summarize from the docs:
Compaction also allows for deletes. A message with a key and a null payload will be treated as a delete from the log. This delete marker will cause any prior message with that key to be removed (as would any new message with that key), but delete markers are special in that they will themselves be cleaned out of the log after a period of time to free up space. The point in time at which deletes are no longer retained is marked as the "delete retention point" in the above diagram.

Answer (score 0):

From 0.10.1.0, Kafka supports log compaction and deletion to co-exist.

Modify `cleanup.policy` to take a comma separated list of valid policies, i.e., `cleanup.policy=compact,delete`

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-71%3A+Enable+log+compaction+and+deletion+to+co-exist